# django unittest without database connection

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to write a unittest that will check if the correct error message is returned in case the database connection hits exception. I've tried to use `connection.creation.destroy_test_db(':memory:')` but it didn't work as I expected. I suppose I should either remove the tables or somehow cut the db connection. Is any of those possible?

Comment: Maybe you can raise a DatabaseError and catch it.
from django.db import DatabaseError
raise DatabaseError

Here the list of default django exceptions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/

Comment: I am confused. The question is titled "without connection", but in the body you said you are trying to assert the message is returned when there's an exception. Like what? Duplicate key? The title and the body don't quite match and I am just confused. Clarification?

Comment: No connection to the database raises DatabaseError exception, which is what I'm trying to cause and assert the error message my webapp prints in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dec, 2021 there is the library [Django Mockingbird](https://pypi.org/project/djangomockingbird/).

With this you can mock the object that would be retrieved from db.

```
from djangomockingbird import mock_model

@mock_model('myapp.myfile.MyModel')
def test_my_test():
    some_test_query = MyModel.objects.filter(bar='bar').filter.(foo='foo').first()
    #some more code
    #assertions here
```

Answer (score 5):

I found my answer in the presentation [Testing and Django by Carl Meyer](https://pycon-2012-notes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_and_django.html). Here is how I did it:

```
from django.db import DatabaseError
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client
import mock

class NoDBTest(TestCase):
    cursor_wrapper = mock.Mock()
    cursor_wrapper.side_effect = DatabaseError

    @mock.patch("django.db.backends.util.CursorWrapper", cursor_wrapper)
    def test_no_database_connection(self):
        response = self.client.post('/signup/', form_data)
        self.assertEqual(message, 'An error occured with the DB')
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like this is a job for [mocking](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/). For example, if you are using MySQL, you can put  a `side_effect` on `connect` method, like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from mock import patch
import MySQLdb


class DBTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_connection_error(self):
        with patch.object(MySQLdb, 'connect') as connect_method:
            connect_method.side_effect = Exception("Database Connection Error")

            # your assertions here
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I did it slightly different, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for django's actual http response code in case of a database connection timeout when using `pymysql`. The following test confirmed it's a `401 Unauthorized` when `pymysql` raises an `OperationalError`.

```python
from unittest.mock import patch

import pymysql
from django.test import TestCase, Client


class TestDatabaseOutage(TestCase):
    client = None

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_database_connection_timeout_returns_401(self):
        with patch.object(pymysql, 'connect') as connect_method:
            message = "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'some_database.example.com' ([Errno 110] Connection timed out)"
            connect_method.side_effect = pymysql.OperationalError(2003, message)
            response = self.client.get('/')
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 401)
```

[image: 401 Unauthorized http cat]